# Lang attribute - Kazakhstan unknown language

Tags: html

I am trying to get Kazakhstan dictionary and flag with lang attribute on span.

I achieved on getting other countries' flag and dictionary but not with Kazakhstan.

I tried kk, kk-KZ, kk_KK etc with no result!

Answer (score 0):

Try these

- ISO 639-1 kk (nevermind)
- ISO 639-2,3 kaz
- Glottolog kaza1248
- Linguasphere 44-AAB-cc

Comment: I tried each one of them but "Unknown language" with a strange flag before it renders.

Comment: Maybe the languages in Kazakhstan use Cyrillic instead?

Comment: Also heard the government switched the script to (I think) a modified Latin script. (Not sure)